# How to add a RepeaterItem to an asp:Repeater using the Controls() method

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I have declared an asp:Repeater on my page with ID="AnswersRepeater". I am calling the below segment of code when the user clicks a button on the page to load additional data from a DataSet denoted as "ds". I need to understand the control hierarchy of an asp:repeater so I can add back in the items the repeater had after rebinding to the datasource like below:

```
Dim currentItems As New ArrayList(AnswersRepeater.Items)
AnswersRepeater.DataSource = ds
AnswersRepeater.DataBind()
For Each item As RepeaterItem In currentItems
   AnswersRepeater.Controls.Add(item)
Next
```

The problem is, the RepeaterItems are not added in the correct place within the repeater control's hierarchy. I need to find the item template and append the items in currentItems array to it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be directly editing the controls of the Repeater control, the idea is you bind to a data source and it dynamically creates controls for you based on that data source.

You'd be better adding the items you already have to your data source `ds` and then just binding once.

Comment: I am unable to add items to my datasource because it's a postback and I need to add incremental data to the end. So I bind the new data and then add the previous controls back on. Do you know of a way I can add incremental data to a repeater or even a different control like listview to output my list of controls? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you are unable to add to the datasource? You could use LINQ and `Union` the old dataset with the new? It's hard to help more without knowing exactly what your data is representing before and after the postback.